# How to allow selecting some texts on the posts that are disabled from selecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger, blogspot

I have already asked this question on StackExchange Webmasters. I added a html/javascript code on my blogger website for disabling copying of contents. The code is:

```
<script src='demo-to-prevent-copy-paste-on-blogger_files/googleapis.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'> if(typeof document.onselectstart!="undefined" ) {document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false" ); } else{document.onmousedown=new Function ("return false" );document.onmouseup=new Function ("return false"); } </script>
```

If I want to allow selecting only some texts from the page? For Example if I want to provide some codes to my reader, how can I allow them just to copy the code but not the whole post?

Thanks in Advance :) my site → [www.aryanpoudel.com.np](http://aryanpoudel.com.np)

Answer (score 2):

First, you cannot disallow copying text from your website. All the text is sent to the user's browser and can therefore also be copied. This measure does only disallow users without much IT expierience not to copy the text.

To solve your problem, it is better to use CSS for that purpose. There is a CSS property called `user-select` which can be set to none. This disallows the user selection of text on the element, the property is set to. Please make sure to use also the browser prefixes for user-select, because it is not yet supported by all major browsers without prefix.

```
.element {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

You can find the browser compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none

If you want to make only parts of your page selectable, you can do that by adding the user-select property to the `body` element of your page or to the `*` selector. If you want to make some element selectable, just reset the CSS styles changing the property back to `user-select: text` again.

Comment: Can anyone answer in a simple language? I am just a beginner in coding field. Just tell me where to put the code. :)

Comment: Do you have a CSS file with all the styles of your page? Add to this file the code above and replace .element with body. This disables the selection for every element. If you want to enable the selection for one element you need to give this element a class (in the html) like selectable. Then you can give elements with this class the property user-select: text (similar to the above example, but with .selectable and user-select: text.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve what you are looking for is:

```js
function getSelectedText() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
  } else if (window.document.getSelection) {
    txt =window.document.getSelection();
  } else if (window.document.selection) {
    txt = window.document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return txt;
}
function removeSelection() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    if (window.getSelection().empty) {
      window.getSelection().empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
  } else if (document.selection) {
    document.selection.empty();
  }
}
var wordSelectables = ["number", "video", "computer"];
document.onmouseup = function() {
  var selText = getSelectedText().toString();
  if (wordSelectables.indexOf(selText) == -1) {
    removeSelection();
  }
}
```

```html
number video <p>video</p>computer

<input value="videocomputer">
```

Comment: This solution does not prevent copying: You can just copy before you release the mouse click (mouseup event). This means: mouse down - select - CTRL+C - mouse up

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 this is not the full solution but only the first draft on how this can be solved without css. It's very easy to add the keyboard events and prevent copy. In any case there is no secure way to prevent user scraping.  I apreciate your answer.